# Equations with Dot Products

Tags: matrices

I'm having trouble with this problem - 
Let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ be vectors satisfying
$\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v} = 3, \mathbf{u} \cdot\mathbf{w} = 4, \mathbf{v} \cdot\mathbf{w} = 5.$ Then what are
$(\mathbf{u} + 2 \mathbf{v})\cdot\mathbf{w}, (\mathbf{w} - \mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v}, (3\mathbf{v} - 2 \mathbf{w})\cdot\mathbf{u}$ equal to?

I've tried writing equations, but they don't seem to lead me anywhere...

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I've corrected your symbol choice for the dot product. For future reference, you should use `\cdot` instead of `\bullet`.

Comment: @J.G. Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that [**distributive law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties) holds for dot product then for example

$$(\mathbf{u}+2\mathbf{v})\cdot\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{w}+2\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{w}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you! I thought that because they were vectors, it wouldn't apply. Have a good day!

Comment: @user588857 You can easily check that by the definition! You are welcome, Bye.